# Has there been a processor architecture that included commands that move arrays of data in the memory with one opcode?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu

In traditional processors one move operation can at most move one word between memory locations and optionally increment or decrement the registers which point to those memory locations. In x86 architecture it is realized with `movs` operation, in PDP-11 as `mov` with auto-increment or auto-decrement addressing.

But I wonder whether there is any architecture that has an opcode for moving the entire memory area, like "mov *source, destination, length*"?

It seems to me that having such opcode in the architecture would allow to reduce load on the CPU by relegating array move job to the low-level circuits, maybe, memory controller. This increases parallelism and improves performance since the memory controller is located closer to the physical memory.

After encountering such opcode the CPU would send message to the memory controller and continue with further commands after this one.
Once the moving job is done, the memory controller may set or clear certain bit of processor flags register so that the program to know that the memory move task is done or would trigger an interrupt.

Has this idea been ever realized? If not, why?

Comment: I can't answer if there has ever been an implementation of that idea.  What I do know is that for operations such as you describe is usually implemented in a DMA controller rather than with specific processor instructions.

Comment: One example would be the DEC VAX [MOVC3/MOVC5 instructions](https://documentation.help/VAX11/op_MOVC.htm).

Comment: @greybeard WOW! This again proves that DEC architectures are the greatest!

Comment: @greybeard but it seems, the program cannot continue after this instruction until it is done. My idea was that the program should continue and find that the array move is done from a PSW bit or from an interrupt.

Comment: It's bad enough to have to keep a register scoreboard. Imagine multiple MOVC instructions issued: You'd have to keep track off address ranges involved. Or just accesses to the destination area in "later" instructions.

Answer (score 1):

X86 does the actual move with one op code. A highly complex instruction that sets the source and destination address and the number of bytes would be unnecessary. Specifying registers with these three items is complicated enough.

Now your comments indicate that you want an asynchronous instruction. If I want an asynchronous memcpy then I call memcpy to run in a background thread. And if I want more I can call 8 memcpy’s to run on 8 background threads, and any processor does that without any complicated hardware changes.